# How do I calculate the amount of power needed to push an object in my weird physics enigine?

Tags: python, math

I have a physics engine that moves objects like this:

```
speed = 10
while game_running == True:
     speed *= 0.9
     position += speed
```

I want to calculate the amount of speed required to move an object x pixels. I can't figure out how, aside from brute force. Is there any way to efficiently calculate the speed required to move objects? (To move an object you set the speed variable)

Comment: You are asking how to compute the sum of the series `original_speed * 0.9 * (1 + 0.9 + 0.9**2 + 0.9**3 + ...)`

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum

Comment: No, I want to calculate it backward, not forwards. My code already computes the sum.

Comment: You have the equation: `total_move = original_speed * 0.9 * (1 + 0.9 + 0.9**2 + 0.9**3 + ...)`. You know the value of `total_move`, and you want to calculate `original_speed`. There is no "backwards" or "forwards" here.

Comment: Yes, but is there any way to calculate the value of original speed from total move?

Comment: Yes. Of course there is. `total_move = original_speed * something`. Divide both sides of this equation by `something`. What do you get?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just completely lost, I'm sorry if I am wasting your time.

Comment: If `something` is nonzero, then the equation `total_move = original_speed * something` is equivalent to the equation `total_move / something = original_speed * something / something` which is equivalent to the equation `total_move / something = original_speed` so there you have it, `original_speed = total_move / something`.

Comment: So I just need to solve "something"?

Comment: You need to calculate `0.9 * (1 + 0.9 + 0.9**2 + 0.9**3 + ...)`